# Alternatives to Spring State Machine

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, activiti, spring-statemachine

I have used Spring state machine with some basic Spring MVC application. I have to admit, it is pretty easy to configure and use.

But it has many limitations as well, mainly because of it being in very early stages of development.

I also came across some workflow engines like **Activiti** which is [an open-source workflow engine written in Java](http://activiti.org/) and **stateless4j** which is a [Lightweight Java State Machine](https://github.com/oxo42/stateless4j). They look much more polished and sophisticated.

I wanted to know what is the difference between these and Spring State Machine (Advantages or disadvantages).

Comment: Don't no much about Spring State Machine but Activiti is really good tool for workflow modeling, you can try activiti Explorer (Web APP) to  know more about it's features.

Comment: Activiti is a workflow engine so it's kinda different beast. If you say that stateless4j is more sophisticated, could you give an example what it can do what spring statemachine cannot do?

Comment: sorry @JanneValkealahti I was talking about Activiti .. where do we use Workflow Engine and where do we use simple state machines then ?

Comment: Not really required but most likely a state machine is a building block for a workflow engine. It really is an application which have a lot of bells and whistles(integration components) around its own workflow states and business processes. Think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine explains it rather well.

Comment: @JanneValkealahti Thanks :)

Comment: It depresses me that this obviously off topic question has 4 up votes.

Answer (score 1):

I would say so a Workflow Engine is a subset of State Machine. With a State Machine you can do much more things and you can think a Workflow Engine like a library for a State Machine, with use cases that are pre-configured but when you want something out of ordinary then you have to make your hands dirty again with a State Machine.